# Wordpress url structure from old website

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

I have a problem converting my old website to Wordpress regarding URL structure.

My old website has this kind of structure for category ***Cambodia***: http://www.readyclickandgo.com/~Cambodia/index.php

My new Wordpress website has structure like this:
http://www.readyclickandgo.com/cambodia/

I really should have the same structure since i really don't want to lose Google pagerank, so i have to make the same structure like on my old website.

I have tried using 301 redirect from ***www.readyclickandgo.com/cambodia/*** to ***www.readyclickandgo.com/~cambodia/***, but it gives me 404 error.

Does anybody know how can i accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: Add the redirect from www.readyclickandgo.com/~cambodia/ to www.readyclickandgo.com/cambodia/ Google will update its links and you end up with better looking urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect from www.readyclickandgo.com/cambodia/ to www.readyclickandgo.com/~cambodia/

Instead of trying this, why can't you do the reverse?

**www.readyclickandgo.com/~cambodia/ to www.readyclickandgo.com/cambodia/**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this Plugin
http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/
After installing the plugin. in the left side of the dasboard there is a menu named Redirection and under redirection click on Quick redirect link.

Cheers.